# Parted Magic filesystem went RAW of external HDD

Tags: partition-recovery

Hi I have ran http://html5.litten.com/how-to-fix-external-disk-drive-suddenly-became-raw/
and got a small 100mb partition back of my external hdd, but the actual partition (500gb) is still raw. Somehow it only fixed the filesystem hidden partition and not the main one.

the parted magic 2013 cd boots fine and even lists all files on the ntfs partition. the testdisk tool also says it is ntfs, windows 8.1 still thinks it is raw.

The testdisk thinks that the mbr is ok, but the mft is not. and testdisk cannot fix it.
[image]
I have fixed the heads and sector with the geometry and the 2nd partition file list shows ALL files, but somehow the 2nd partition is still unavailable in windows. it seems that the master file table is corrupt and cannot be fixed with testdisk.
[image]

**edit** will try zero assumption recovery, found the suggestion here: [HDD is not accessible. Possible MFT corruption. How do i proceed?](https://superuser.com/questions/237852/hdd-is-not-accessible-possible-mft-corruption-how-do-i-proceed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ran testdisk to fix partition table and used check disk.

> chkdsk F: /F

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: Cool, it just wasn't implicit in the answer